# A Cart for a Bicycle

Tags: trailer

I was looking at building a Cart/cargo for attaching to the back of my bike.
Are you guys aware of any DIY kits or manufacturers that can  build it to my specifications. 
I did look at some on the market, but they all seemed to be limited and are of less dimensions. I was looking for building something about 1.5*1*1(Length width and height).
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are those dimensions in meters?

Comment: I have seen a M-Wave cargo trailer on Amazon with the same dimensions (if English unis) in the cargo box for about $150.  The frame is designed the same as my child trailer and I have beat that one up good and it still holds.  Any reason for DIY?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [this Wicycle kit](http://www.wicycle.com/cargo_diy_kit_bicycle_trailer.php) may fit your needs. You buy the dimensional material (metal bars in this case) to whatever size you need locally, and the specialized cargo hardware is included.